# Taking notes of time usage during game

Tags: rules, time-management, wesley-so

While I know taking making any notes during a game is against the rules (and [Wesley So was disqualified for this](https://www.facebook.com/wesleyso/posts/10152886311127857)), does this include denoting the time usage after each move?

Comment: A link for the Wesley So case, please ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/wesleyso/posts/10152886311127857

Comment: See also https://www.chess.com/news/view/breaking-wesley-so-forfeited-in-round-9-9186 for a more detailed report.

Answer (score 15):

FIDE rules allow you to record the time:

> 8.1.4     The scoresheet shall be used only for recording the moves, the times of the clocks, offers of a draw, matters relating to a claim and
>   other relevant data.

https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article

USCF rules also allow you to record the time:

> 20C. Use of notes prohibited. The use of notes made during the game as
>   an aid to memory is forbidden, aside from the actual recording of the
>   moves, draw offers, and clock times, and the header information
>   normally found on a scoresheet.

U.S. Chess Federation. United States Chess Federation's Official Rules of Chess, Sixth Edition (Kindle Locations 1925-1927). Diversified Publishing. Kindle Edition.